# "Gradle location is incorrect" when migrating android project from eclipse to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I followed the this guide to migrate my android project
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

I have exported a Gradle file through eclipse. When I try to import the project to android studio, I am stucked with this error. Please help[image]

Android studio version 0.6.1

Answer (score 1):

That's not asking for your project's Gradle structured files it wants the location of your Gradle Build tools or Gradle configuration file.

It defaults as a file called .gradle in your user home directory I think.
Mine points to:

```
/home/indiv/.gradle
```

---

Although, I found it easier to import my Eclipse projects into Studio (as Eclipse projects) than export a Gradle project from Eclipse and then import to Studio.

Your choice though.